# Как получить значения из бд (mysql) только NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Использую Yii, CDbCriteria. Но это и не важно, наверное. 
В общем есть 3 поля с 3мя разными значения ячейки `1`, `0` и `NULL`.

Если выбираю ВСЕ, то показывет 3 значения.
Если выбираю только `NULL(where var = NULL)`, то НИЧЕГО не показывает.
Если выбираю только не `1` и не `0` (`where var != 1 AND var != 0`), то НИЧЕГО не показывает.

??

Comment: Такая проверка годится для integer-ов `where var != 1`. Может ваш столбец имеет тип varchar?

Comment: LEQADA, данные у меня BIT(1)

Comment: Можно еще так допустим: COALESCE(var,2) != 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте проверку правильно:

```
... WHERE var IS NULL
```

Или обратную

```
... WHERE var IS NOT NULL
```

В [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) написано, что нельзя использовать арифметические операции с `NULL`:

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Comment: хм... я был уверен, что `var != 1 and var != 2` должен вернуть `null`, но не возвращает... Видно потому что проверка `null != 1` и `null = 1` возвращает `null` вместо true/false